# Access "THIS_" COM parameter via C# ComImport

Tags: c#, com, interop

Most com methods have a signature like this:

```
STDMETHOD(someFunc) (THIS_ ParamType param) PURE;
```

Which translates to C# via ComImport as:

```
[PreserveSig()]
int someFunc(MarshaledParamType param);
```

Is there some way to preserve the "THIS_" parameter in the PInvoke signature? So that I can do something like:

```
int someFunc(IntPtr ptrToCOMInstance, MarshaledParamType param);
```

or

```
int someFunc(IMyCOMClass comInstance, MarshaledParamType param);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a fake annotation, representing the *this* pointer that gets passed to a class method.  You don't actually declare it in neither C++ nor C#, it gets passed without writing it out explicitly.

But do note the difference between the server and the client.  In the server, you use the *this* keyword to recover that pointer.  In the client, you have the object reference.  For example:

```
Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
Word.Document doc = new Word.Document();
```

The app and doc variables are the object references you are looking for.  The value of *this* inside Word's implementation of the Application and Document interfaces.  Ignoring the intricacies of RCWs for a moment.